# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity features not working when published to server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app that uses Entity Framework and Microsoft Identity for user accounts. I am able to run the application in debug and create an account/login etc, however, when published to iis, I receive the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBzTO.png)

The offending bit of code is in _Layout.cshtml below, which, as far as I can tell, is not implementing user identity like it does in debug.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using MyApp.Areas.Identity.Data
@inject UserManager<MyAppUser> userManger
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div style="height:30px; margin-top:0px;">
                    <img class="navbar-brand" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" src="~/images/AASLogoDarkMinimal.png" />
                </div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">My App</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial.cshtml" />






                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">

                          @{if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                var user = await userManger.GetUserAsync(User);

                                var rolesArray = userManger.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;

                                if (rolesArray.Contains("Administrator") || rolesArray.Contains("Sales Administrator"))
                                {
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-info" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Admin Tools
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        @if (rolesArray.Contains("Administrator"))
                                            {
                                        <a type="button" class="dropdown-item btn btn-info btn-sm" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">User Management</a>
                                            }
                                        @if (rolesArray.Contains("Sales Administrator"))
                                            {
                                        <a type="button" class="dropdown-item btn btn-info btn-sm" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Price Management</a>
                                            }

                                    </div>

                                </li>

                                }

                            }
                            }

                    </ul>


                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Application
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Could it be something to do with IdentityHostingStartup.cs?

**IdentityHostingStartup.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyApp.Areas.Identity.Data;
using MyApp.Data;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(MyApp.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace MyApp.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<MyAppAuthDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAppAuthDbContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyAppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppAuthDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


           
           
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextSQLIdentity>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLIdentDB")));


           

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);


            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            
            services.AddRazorPages();

        
        }

       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
              
                app.UseHsts();
            }
         
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the user you are logging in have an associated roles?

Comment: I'm not able to get to the login screen, this is the error that occurs on the application load. I have [Authorize] on the Home controller Index, which should prompt the login screen to be returned. This is what happens in debug but when published to the server, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this line:

```
var rolesArray = userManger.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
```

is returning null, and therefore the next lines that use .Contains will fail with NRE.

That would suggest to me that your logged in user has no roles.

BTW Calling `.Result` on a `Task` is not good practice and will sometimes result in a locked task.

Comment: I'm not getting to the stage where I can log in a user. I have [Authorize] on the home controller Index, which prompts the login screen to show (in debug that is). When published, it fails at the first hurdle and returns the error. Thanks for the heads up on .Result. That was from a copy/paste solution.

Comment: When the app is launched, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated() should be returning false, but it looks like it returns true, allowing the nested code to run and cause an error.

Comment: I found the issue! I needed to disable Windows Authentication and enable anonymous authentication in IIS on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue! I needed to disable Windows Authentication and enable anonymous authentication in IIS on the server.